# IIS Rewrite catching all requests instead of matching patterns

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect requests for specific directories to a different domain with the same directory. The code works as intended except that even requests that don't match the pattern are being redirected. Is there something I'm missing so all non matching requests are processed normally by the server?

Sample incoming URL is http://www.inbounddomain.com/STRING2.NSF/some-really-long-file-name-that-needs-to-be-appended-to-the-redirect

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="Mod-Rewrite" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\imodrewi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="bitness64" />
    </handlers>

<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Redirect for STRING2.NSF" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*?)(?:STRING2.NSF/|$)(.*)" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.redirectdomain.com/STRING2.NSF/{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```